# Subtract a number from an array in succession - decreasing the original number and array items

Tags: php, math

I need a function in PHP where I have a number I want to subtract from 3 items in an array but one after the other decreasing the original number and if it depletes one of the 3 items moves on to the next.

for example if these are my starting variable and array

```php
$original_number = 15;

$pots = [
    'pot_1' => 10,
    'pot_2' => 10,
    'pot_3' => 10,
];
```

Lets say I want to subtract 15 from all three pots items one after the other leaving a pot item at 0 (if it goes in to minus) and then moving on to the next pot until the original number is depleted.

So that would mean this would be the outcome...

```php
$original_number = 0;

$pots = [
    'pot_1' => 0,
    'pot_2' => 5,
    'pot_3' => 10,
];
```

Comment: You would be better off if you use an array as opposed to 3 variables.

Comment: Thats fine to do... have updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function substract($number, $array) {
   for($array as $key => $value) {
      if($value > $number) {
         $array[$key] = $value - $number;
         $number = 0;
         return $number;
      } else {
         $number -= $value;
         $array[$key] = 0;
      }
   }
   return $number;
}
```

You could then have `$original_number = substract($original_number, $pots)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I have only just had chance to test this out and it works amazingly... thank you very much!